# Will files added to an encrypted drive be encrypted as well?

Tags: disk-encryption

If we do disk encryption on a drive and add some files later on, will they be encrypted or not?

Comment: Please note that disk encryption only helps when somebody steals your hardware. It does NOT prevent rogue software from reading files on disk as the OS de-crypts files for everything running.It would not help against wannacry++, for example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it will be encrypted.

This is (basically) because of the operating system replacing several calls for file I/O and other operations of ran in encrypted "mode". [This paper](https://www.symantec.com/content/en/us/enterprise/white_papers/b-pgp_how_wholedisk_encryption_works_WP_21158817.en-us.pdf) states on a very basic level what happens:

> When a user requests access to a file (i.e., creates, opens, or deletes a file), the request is sent to the operating system input/output (I/O) manager, which forwards the request to the file system manager. The file system manager processes data in blocks.
>
> Life with encryption: business as usual
>
> Most whole disk encryption software operates in conjunction with the
> file system architecture. It filters I/O operations for one or more
> file systems or file system volumes. When a drive is encrypted with
> whole disk encryption for the first time, it converts unencrypted
> drive blocks into encrypted blocks one at a time (Figure 2).